# android.support.v7.preference.EditTextPreference how to set keyboard to numeric

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-preferences

`android:inputType` is not working on `EdidtTextPreference` from support library. Is changing the input type even possible with this preference? I want a preference with a numeric keyboard. More specifically I will want to set a custom Keyboard, but I can't seem to even open the default one with this preference. If it is not possible with `EditTextPreference`, can someone give me an idea how I would go about doing what I desire?

```
<android.support.v7.preference.EditTextPreference
    android:key="key"
    android:title="title"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:dialogMessage="title"
    android:inputType="number"  />
```

Comment: "I will want to set a custom Keyboard" -- that is not possible. The user, not you, chooses the input method editor. At best, you give the input method editor hints as to what you would like (e.g., via `android:inputType`). The `support.v7` edition of `EditTextPreference` does not say that it supports configuring the `EditText`, and looking at [the code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/preference/src/android/support/v7/preference/EditTextPreference.java), I do not even see where the `EditText` comes from, let alone how it gets configured.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yea, that is what I am affraid as well, that there is no way to get to the `EditText`. I have found it in the source code though. The `PreferenceFragmentCompat` starts the `PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat` which has the `EditText`. There are some handlers that might let me get to the `EditText`, I will know more on Monday when I get back to work :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EditTextPreference - only numeric value inputType - isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42804842/edittextpreference-only-numeric-value-inputtype-isnt-working)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the solution is quite easy. Since `android:inputType="number"` didn't seem to work, I went with this:

**PreferenceFragment.java**

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    EditTextPreference preference = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("key");
    EditText et = preference.getEditText();
    if (et != null) {
        et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        //in fact, you can do whatever you can normally with an EditText here
    }
}
```

Although I'm not sure if this is how it works with the latest androidx Preference.